# Can I use bottom up, middle out, or top down approaches with fabletools:reconcile?

Tags: r, time-series, multilevel-analysis

I have been learning how to use the very handy fable package (along with forecast, fabletools, etc.) and I have looked at [fpp2](https://otexts.com/fpp2/) and [fpp3](https://otexts.com/fpp3/) in the processes. fpp2 chapter 10 talks about hierarchical forecasting and the bottom up, middle out, and top down methods in which you forecast one level of a series and aggregate / disaggregate the series up and / or down. This is done with the `hts` and `forecast` packages.

fpp3 talks about the `fable` package but I dont see (apologies if I missed it) a section talking about forecasting hierarchies. What I have found thus far is that `fable` forecasts all the series in a hierarchy together as opposed to the older approach of forecasting one level. And you can use `reconcile` to... well reconcile these with each other. I've looked for more explanation and examples but the only ones I've found use `reconcile` with `min_trace` like this:

```
if (requireNamespace("fable", quietly = TRUE)) {
library(fable)
lung_deaths_agg <- as_tsibble(cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)) %>%
  aggregate_key(key, value = sum(value))

lung_deaths_agg %>%
  model(lm = TSLM(value ~ trend() + season())) %>%
  reconcile(lm = min_trace(lm)) %>%
  forecast()
}
```

So my questions are:

- Are there other more in depth resources I'm missing for forecasting using `fable`?

  - Specifically a list of all the reconciliation methods and how they should be used?
- Can you use something like bu, mo, td reconciliation with `reconcile`?
- Are approaches like `min_trace` considered better in all respects than bu, mo, td approaches and so I should just not worry about it?

Thanks very much for any help anyone could offer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hm. Unfortunately, `?fabletools::reconcile` gives a *very* rudimentary help page. I am not privy to the internals, but what I *can* tell you may already be helpful.

I strongly suspect that `min_trace` implements an *optimal reconciliation* approach which, yes, typically performs better than bottom-up, top-down and middle-out. It looks like FPP3 does not have the relevant chapter yet, so I would recommend [Chapter 10 in FPP2](https://otexts.com/fpp2/hierarchical.html), especially [section 10.7](https://otexts.com/fpp2/reconciliation.html).

Specifically, the flavor that `min_trace` gives is probably optimal reconciliation through trace minimization ([Wickramasurya, Athanasopoulos & Hyndman, 2019, *JASA*](https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.2018.1448825) - yes, the latter two are the authors of FPP). That paper also references a number of earlier papers on optimal reconciliation, e.g., the original one by [Athanasopoulos et al. (2009, *IJF*)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2008.07.004), with a corrigendum by [Athanasopoulos et al. (2015, *IJF*)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207014001113), and the one by [Hyndman et al., (2011, *CS&DA*)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207014001113).

These papers and the FPP2 section should give you a very good foundation to understand what is happening, even in the absence of thorough documentation. Alternatively, you could work with the older `hts` package for hierarchical time series, which implements almost the same functionalities (for now).